# Why does my VBA script looking for a subfolder in Outlook randomly work and then sometimes it does not?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a script in Excel VBA that looks for specific emails in a subfolder in a shared inbox at work.  Each person on the team has their own personal inbox and then we all have access to a single inbox that is for the team.  I have the Outlook library checked in References.  The majority of the time it works on my computer.  When my coworkers try to run the script, it will work sometimes but often it does not run.  Then whenever I run it on my machine, it will work and THEN run perfectly fine on my coworker's machine.

It fails when the script is trying to set the "userf" variable to an `Outlook.MAPIfolder` object.  The subfolder exists in the shared inbox on all of our machines, so I am not sure why it randomly works and sometimes it does not.

I put a comment down towards the bottom of the code where the script crashes.

Here is the code:

```
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim f As Outlook.MAPIFolder, subf As Outlook.MAPIFolder, userf As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim currentitem As Object
Dim currentatt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim firstDayNo As Variant, monthNo As Variant
Dim wbMonth As String, attachmentname As String, fpath As String, rngName As String, datestring As String
Dim five9 As Outlook.Items, five9rng As Outlook.Items
Dim wbCopy As Workbook, wbPaste As Workbook
Dim ReadyDone As Boolean, CallsDone As Boolean, ACWDone As Boolean, LoginDone As Boolean, NotReadyDone As Boolean, monthReal As Boolean, dayReal As Boolean
Dim newdate As Date
Dim daysInMonthSelected As Long

monthReal = False
Do Until monthReal
monthNo = InputBox("Enter the month number you wish to create the Agent Reason Code Summary for.")
If monthNo = vbNullString Then
ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
ElseIf (monthNo < 1 Or monthNo > 12) Then
MsgBox "Input must be a numeric value between 1 and 12.  Try again."
Else
monthReal = True
End If
Loop

ReadyDone = False
CallsDone = False
ACWDone = False
LoginDone = False
NotReadyDone = False

Select Case monthNo
Case 1
wbMonth = "Jan"
Case 2
wbMonth = "Feb"
Case 3
wbMonth = "Mar"
Case 4
wbMonth = "Apr"
Case 5
wbMonth = "May"
Case 6
wbMonth = "Jun"
Case 7
wbMonth = "Jul"
Case 8
wbMonth = "Aug"
Case 9
wbMonth = "Sep"
Case 10
wbMonth = "Oct"
Case 11
wbMonth = "Nov"
Case 12
wbMonth = "Dec"
End Select

strMnth = CStr(monthNo)

yr = Year(Date)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\hrn-prod-nas2\enrollment_operations\WFM\Agent Reason Code\" & yr & "\" & monthNo & " " & wbMonth & "_Agent Reason Code Summary.xlsm", FileFormat:=52

If strMnth = "" Then
ThisWorkbook.Close
Else

dayReal = False
Do Until dayReal
firstDayNo = InputBox("Enter the first day number.")

daysInMonthSelected = MonthDays(monthNo)
If firstDayNo = vbNullString Then
ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
ElseIf (firstDayNo < 1 Or firstDayNo > daysInMonthSelected) Then
MsgBox "Input must be a numeric value between 1 and " & daysInMonthSelected & ".  Try again."
Else
datestring = monthNo & "/" & firstDayNo & "/" & Year(Date)
newdate = CDate(datestring)
If newdate >= Date Then
MsgBox "You can only create an ARCS for days in the past.  Enter a date before today."
Else
dayReal = True
End If
End If
Loop

strFirstDay = CStr(firstDayNo)

If strFirstDay = "" Then
ThisWorkbook.Close
Else

Set olNs = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set f = olNs.Folders("WFM")
Set subf = f.Folders("Inbox")
Set userf = subf.Folders("Five9 Reports") 'This line will throw a run-time error
Set five9 = userf.Items
Set five9rng = five9.restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(newdate + 1, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")
Set five9rng = five9rng.restrict("[ReceivedTime]<'" & Format(newdate + 2, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")
Set wbPaste = ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: as a side note you can clean up about 14 lines of code into 1. `wbMonth = Format(MonthNo & "/1/2017","mmm")`

Comment: I've run into the same issue with Outlook failing to find subfolders in shared inboxes when referenced through VBA. The only "workaround" I ever found is that the folder references would consistently work immediately after Outlook had been opened. Hopefully someone else knows an Outlook setting or different way to resolve the folders in VBA that fixes this.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Or even `wbMonth = MonthName(MonthNo, True)` which will correctly return the month name irrespective of the user's default date format. (Your `Format` returns `"Jan"` for me, irrespective of the month, because I live in a sane dd/mm/yyyy country. ;) )

Comment: Do your coworkers have other accounts/profiles setup in Outlook also? A screenshot of the folders pane in outlook would help

Comment: @YowE3K - upvote comment, crack at my place of origin aside ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602063/1571407