# Retrieve shared mailbox mails from root folders to subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code currently which I think should pull all mail items from a shared mailbox folder.

I know there is some problem in looping all folders in shared mailbox from root.

```vb
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim eFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim ItemCount As Long
    
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olShareName = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("example@example.com")
    
    For Each eFolder In OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folders
     
        Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folders(eFolder.Name)
        
        Set olItems = Folder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Range("From_date").Value & "' and [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Range("to_date").Value & "'")
        
        If olItems.Count > 0 Then
            ReDim arrResults(1 To olItems.Count, 1 To 5)
            ItemCount = 0
            For Each OutlookMail In olItems
                ItemCount = ItemCount + 1
                arrResults(ItemCount, 1) = OutlookMail.Subject
                arrResults(ItemCount, 2) = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
                arrResults(ItemCount, 3) = OutlookMail.SenderName
                arrResults(ItemCount, 4) = OutlookMail.Size
                arrResults(ItemCount, 5) = OutlookMail.Categories
            Next OutlookMail
            Worksheets("import").Range("A5").Resize(UBound(arrResults, 1), 5) = arrResults
        Else
            MsgBox "No items found!", vbExclamation
        End If
        
        Set olItems = Nothing
        
        Set Folder = Nothing
        Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
        Set olShareName = Nothing
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Next eFolder
```

Comment: I don't know much about VBA, but is this really correct? `Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folders(eFolder.Name)` Doesn't eFolder already contain the folder?

Comment: please add more explanation than just "it's not working as expected" and a code copy paste. please tell us the error and where it happens, so it's not a guessing game

Comment: @dv3.
Sorry for not mentioning it before.
No errors and also I did specify that I have problem with looping all folders inside sharedmailbox to get email items

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that by default Outlook caches shared folders in the primary mailbox's OST file. Subfolders are not cached. Try to disable the shared folder caching in the Exchange account properties dialog.